# Bug in javascript engine? Array.prototype.sort with Function.call for callback

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.  The following scenario fails in both Chrome and Firefox so I'm not entirely sure.  Could someone let me know why this isn't working if this is in fact my fault.

Here's a simplified example of the bug:

```
var bObj = {
  list: [4,5,23,5,90,1],
  sort: function() {
    var cb = function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }, that = this;
    this.list.sort(function(a, b) {cb.call(that, a, b);}); 
  }
};
bObj.sort();
console.log(bObj.list);

var wObj = {
  list: [4,5,23,5,90,1],
  sort: function() {
    var cb = function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    };
    this.list.sort(cb); 
  }
};
wObj.sort();
console.log(wObj.list);
```

This outputs:

```
[4, 5, 23, 5, 90, 1]
[1, 4, 5, 5, 23, 90]
```

With Function.call, I needed to maintain context because I was referencing object properties inside the callback.  I ended up getting around the problem with a simple closure.  I would still like to know why this failed.

Thanks

Comment: Instant -1. Don't beg bugs (especially of well-tested code) in titles. Please rewrite it stating just the observations.

Comment: You simply forgot a `return`. The bug is in the user, as usual...

Comment: thanks, there's no hubris.  I wanted to know why this wasnt working.

Comment: From experience, it's really rare (almost impossible?) that there is "bugs" in the language itself unless you are using an alpha/beta version of that language.

Comment: Yeah, I expected it to be my fault.  Thats why I asked.

Comment: The complaint is about the _way_ you asked. You implied that there's a significant chance that it's a bug in JS, not your code. If you expected it to be your fault, why suggest that?

Comment: And please do rewrite/restate the problem given the feedback; questions can be edited. I would normally do so for a *new* SO user..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sort` function is returning nothing:

```
  sort: function() {
    var cb = function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    };
    var that = this;
    this.list.sort(function(a, b) {
      cb.call(that, a, b); // <--- here's your bug in the javascript engine.
    }); 
  }
```

Although, here is what I think is a cleaner approach:

```
  sort: function() {
    var cb = function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    };
    this.list.sort(cb.bind(this)); 
  }
```

Comment: isn't `.bind(this)` useless in this case ?

Comment: The OP wants to be able to access the scope of `bObj` as `this` in the callback function.